# How to evaluate the following? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_1^{n!} x^{-n}{\rm d}x$.

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

How can I evaluate this sum?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_1^{n!} x^{-n} \mathrm{d} x$$
Is there a closed form or a transform that would make it possible not to "CAS" it? Also, it seems to converge, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to think that the sum doesn't converge. Below is the intuitive proof; I think someone else can make this rigorous or prove this to be wrong.

Firstly, for $n=1$,$\int_1^1 x^{-1} dx = 0$. Next, for $n >1$,

$$I_n = \int_{1}^{n!}x^{-n}dx =\frac{1}{-n+1}x^{-n+1}|_1^{n!} = \frac{1}{1-n}[n!^{1-n}-1] = \frac{1}{n-1}\left[1-\frac{1}{n!^{n-1}} \right] $$

as $n\rightarrow\infty$, then $\left[1-\frac{1}{n!^{n-1}}\right]\rightarrow 1$ in a really quick way, since $n!^{n-1}$ explodes fastly; the relevant factor is that $\frac{1}{n!^{n-1}}$ converges to $0$ much, much faster compared to $\frac{1}{n}$ converging to 0.

Thus we can say that $(n-1) I(n)\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, that is, the behaviour of $I(n)$ highly resembles $\frac{1}{n-1}$ as we move to larger values of $n$.

However, we know that $\sum_2^\infty\frac{1}{n-1}$ doesn't converge, which leads me to believe that the sum doesn't converge.

(Hope someone can fix my write-up; don't really now how to express this idea!)

Comment: for $n > 1$, $1 - \frac{1}{n!^{n-1}} > 1 - \frac{1}{2!^{2-1}} = \frac12 \implies \sum\limits_{n=2}^N I_n > \frac12\sum\limits_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n-1}$ and RHS $\to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: yes achille, and what does that mean? I don't get your comment... edit: ah, got it. and that's much easier than mine! lol :D

Comment: You showed that $I_n$ was equal to $1/(n-1)$ times something near 1. Achille observed that this means it's LARGER than $1/(n-1)$ times $1/2$; that means that the sum of the $I_n$s is larger than half the sum of the harmonic series...which diverges. So half of it diverges, too, so the $I_n$ series diverges as well.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the $n=1$ term.  The rest is more than $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_1^2x^{-n}dx$

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I evaluate this sum?*

Start by evaluating the painstakingly simple definite integral inside the series.

> *Is there a closed form*

Yes, $\infty$.

> *Also, it seems to converge*

It sure does, doesn't it ? But you know what they say about appearances... ;-)

> *but I cannot prove it.*

I'd be amazed if you could. :-) Well, if you can't prove that it converges, prove that it diverges. ;-)